# how to convert php unpack() in a similar method in Java

Tags: java, php

I've no coding experience in PHP at all. But while looking for a solution for my Java project, i found an example of the problem in PHP, which incidentally is alien to me.

Can anyone please explain the working and the result of the `unpack('N*',"string")` function of PHP and how to implement it in Java?

An example would help me a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a productive way to ask questions. Please state the problem you're trying to solve first, then ask if there is something like unpack that could be used to solve it.

Comment: the problem, Sir, was i'm trying to understand the MEGA API. A very helpful gentleman has explained and implemented the same in PHP [link]http://julien-marchand.fr/blog/using-the-mega-api-with-php-examples . i was using this info. to understand the API and convert it into JAVA so as to make an android app!

Please help if u now are clear on the problem! :D

Comment: I looked at the code you linked to, and I'm not really sure why it even needs to convert between byte arrays (= strings in PHP) and int arrays. In fact, I suspect it really doesn't, at least not _all_ the time like it currently does.  Still, if you do need to do it for some reason, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[In PHP](http://php.net/unpack) (and [in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html), where PHP copied it from), `unpack("N*", ...)` takes a string (actually representing a sequence of bytes) and parses each 4-byte segment of it as a signed 32-bit big-endian ("**N**etwork byte order") integer, returning them in an array.

There are several ways to do the same in Java, but one way would be to wrap the input byte array in a [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), convert it to an `IntBuffer` and then read the integers from that:

```
public static int[] unpackNStar ( byte[] bytes ) {
    // first, wrap the input array in a ByteBuffer:
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap( bytes );

    // then turn it into an IntBuffer, using big-endian ("Network") byte order:
    byteBuf.order( ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN );
    IntBuffer intBuf = byteBuf.asIntBuffer();

    // finally, dump the contents of the IntBuffer into an array
    int[] integers = new int[ intBuf.remaining() ];
    intBuf.get( integers );
    return integers;
}
```

Of course, if you just want to iterate over the integers, you don't really need the `IntBuffer` or the array:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ButeBuffer.wrap( bytes );
buf.order( ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN );

while ( buf.hasRemaining() ) {
    int num = buf.getInt();
    // do something with num...
}
```

In fact, iterating over a `ByteBuffer` like this is a convenient way to emulate the behavior of even more complicated examples of `unpack()` in Perl or PHP.

(*Disclaimer: I have not tested this code.  I believe it should work, but it's always possible that I may have mistyped or misunderstood something.  Please test before using.*)

Ps. If you're reading the bytes from an input stream, you could also wrap it in a [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and use its [`readInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) method.  Of course, it's also possible to use a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to read the input from a byte array, achieving the same results as the `ByteBuffer` examples above.

Comment: i intend to take the data from a password field and use that in `unpack('N*,...)` the array created will be used to generate hash-code. 

PHP code:
`$b = str_pad($b, 4 * ceil(strlen($b) / 4), "\0");
  return array_values(unpack('N*', $b));`

What would be best?

Comment: You first need to convert the string into a byte array using `String.getBytes()` (with a suitable encoding, e.g. UTF-8), pad the byte array to a multiple of 4 bytes and then use `ByteBuffer` like above. Only, having looked at the PHP code you linked to above, I kind of suspect that you don't actually _need_ to do either of the last steps, and that it may be easier to just work directly with byte arrays instead.