# Json String gots corrupted on Socket PHP & Java

Tags: java, php, sockets

This is my php Socket Server client sending code.

```
namespace Sock;

class SocketClient {

    private $connection;
    private $address;
    private $port;

    public function __construct( $connection ) {
        $address = ''; 
        $port = '';
        socket_getsockname($connection, $address, $port);
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
    
    public function send( $message ) {
        print_r("Message Sent " . $message . "\n");
        socket_write($this->connection, $message . "\n", strlen($message . "\n"));
    }
    
    public function read($len = 1024) {
        if ( ( $buf = @socket_read( $this->connection, $len, PHP_BINARY_READ  ) ) === false ) {
                return null;
        }
        
        return $buf;
    }

    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->address;
    }
    
    public function getPort() {
        return $this->port;
    }
    
    public function close() {
        socket_shutdown( $this->connection );
        socket_close( $this->connection );
    }
}
```

This is my Java client code

```
package me.proiezrush.virtualizorapi.socket;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class ClientConnection extends Thread {

    private final Socket socket;
    private final DataOutputStream dos;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final DataInputStream dis;
    public ClientConnection(Socket socket) throws Exception {
        this.socket = socket;

        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        System.out.println("CONNECTED");
    }

    public void send(String msg) {
        try {
            dos.writeUTF(msg);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String s = receive();
                if (!s.equals("")) {
                    
                    System.out.println(s);
                    if (s.startsWith("[VPSID] ")) {
                        //String a = s.replace("[VPSID] ", "");


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    private String receive() throws Exception {
        int buflen = inputStream.available();
        byte[] rawstring = new byte[buflen];
        dis.read(rawstring, 0, buflen);
        String str = new String(rawstring, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        return str;
    }
}
```

This is the output from the php server

```
{"151":{"vpsid":"151","vps_name":"v1034","uuid":"btdryfgrv5nsmchw","serid":0,"time":"1622952141","edittime":"1623074735","virt":"kvm","uid":"2","plid":"2","hostname":"xxxx","osid":"909","os_name":"ubuntu-20.04-x86_64","iso":"","sec_iso":"","boot":"cda","space":"10","inodes":"0","ram":"2048","burst":"0","swap":"512","cpu":"100","cores":"1","cpupin":"-1","cpu_percent":"0.00","bandwidth":"2000","network_speed":"0","upload_speed":"-1","io":"0","ubc":"","acpi":"1","apic":"1","pae":"0","shadow":"0","vnc":"1","vncport":"5901","vnc_passwd":"","hvm":"0","suspended":"0","suspend_reason":"","nw_suspended":"","rescue":"0","band_suspend":"0","tuntap":"0","ppp":"0","ploop":"0","dns_nameserver":"a:0:{}","osreinstall_limit":"0","preferences":"","nic_type":"virtio","vif_type":"","virtio":"1","pv_on_hvm":"0","disks":"","kvm_cache":"0","io_mode":"0","cpu_mode":"","total_iops_sec":"0","read_bytes_sec":"0","write_bytes_sec":"0","kvm_vga":"0","acceleration":"0","vnc_keymap":"en-us","routing":"0","mg":"","used_bandwidth":"16.50","cached_disk":"a:2:{s:4:\"disk\";a:6:{s:10:\"Filesystem\";s:19:\"\/dev\/mapper\/loop0p1\";s:9:\"1K-blocks\";s:7:\"9740372\";s:4:\"Used\";s:7:\"2052964\";s:9:\"Available\";s:7:\"7173136\";s:4:\"Use%\";s:3:\"23%\";s:10:\"mounted_on\";s:13:\"\/home\/v1034\/0\";}s:5:\"inode\";a:6:{s:10:\"Filesystem\";s:19:\"\/dev\/mapper\/loop0p1\";s:6:\"Inodes\";s:6:\"615296\";s:5:\"IUsed\";s:5:\"79902\";s:5:\"IFree\";s:6:\"535394\";s:5:\"IUse%\";s:3:\"13%\";s:10:\"mounted_on\";s:13:\"\/home\/v1034\/0\";}}","webuzo":"0","disable_ebtables":"0","install_xentools":"0","admin_managed":"0","rdp":"0","topology_sockets":"0","topology_cores":"0","topology_threads":"0","mac":"00:16:3e:2a:1b:56","notes":"","disable_nw_config":"0","locked":"","openvz_features":"","speed_cap":"","numa":"0","bpid":"0","bserid":"0","timezone":"","ha":"0","data":null,"server_name":"localhost","email":"xxxxx@gmail.com","pid":"0","type":"0","os_distro":"ubuntu","stid":[35],"ips":{"155":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XX"}}}
```

But this is what I'm getting in Java output

```
{"151":{"vpsid":"151","vps_name":"v1034","uuid":"btdryfgrv5nsmchw","serid":0,"time":"1622952141","edittime":"1623074735","virt":"kvm","uid":"2","plid":"2","hostname":"quboxhost.com","osid":"909","os_name":"ubuntu-20.04-x86_64","iso":"","sec_iso":"","boot":"cda","space":"10","inodes":"0","ram":"2048","burst":"0","swap":"512","cpu":"100","cores":"1","cpupin":"-1","cpu_percent":"0.00","bandwidth":"2000","network_speed":"0","upload_speed":"-1","io":"0","ubc":"","acpi":"1","apic":"1","pae":"0","shadow":"0","vnc":"1","vncport":"5901","vnc_passwd":"","hvm":"0","suspended":"0","suspend_reason":"","nw_suspended":"","rescue":"0","band_suspend":"0","tuntap":"0","ppp":"0","ploop":"0","dns_nameserver":"a:0:{}","osreinstall_limit":"0","preferences":"","nic_type":"virtio","vif_type":"","virtio":"1","pv_on_hvm":"0","disks":"","kvm_cache":"0","io_mode":"0","cpu_mode":"","total_iops_sec":"0","read_bytes_sec":"0","write_bytes_sec":"0","kvm_vga":"0","acceleration":"0","vnc_keymap":"en-us","routing":"0","mg":"","used_bandwidth":"16.50","cached_disk":"a:2:{s:4:\"disk\";a:6:{s:10:\"Filesystem\";s:19:\"\/dev\/mapper\/loop0p1\";s:9:\"1K-blocks\";s:7:\"9740372\";s:4:\"Used\";s:7:\"2052964\";s:9:\"Available\";s:7:\"7173136\";s:4:\"Use%\";s:3:\"23%\";s:10:\"mounted_on\";s:13:\"\/home\/v1034\/0\";}s:5:\"inode\";a:6:{s:10:\"Filesystem\";s:19:\"\/dev\/mapper\/loop0p1\";s:6:\"Inodes\";s:6:\"615296\";s:5:\"IUsed\";s:5:\"7
9902\";s:5:\"IFree\";s:6:\"535394\";s:5:\"IUse%\";s:3:\"13%\";s:10:\"mounted_on\";s:13:\"\/home\/v1034\/0\";}}","webuzo":"0","disable_ebtables":"0","install_xentools":"0","admin_managed":"0","rdp":"0","topology_sockets":"0","topology_cores":"0","topology_threads":"0","mac":"00:16:3e:2a:1b:56","notes":"","disable_nw_config":"0","locked":"","openvz_features":"","speed_cap":"","numa":"0","bpid":"0","bserid":"0","timezone":"","ha":"0","data":null,"server_name":"localhost","email":"edumaucherni@gmail.com","pid":"0","type":"0","os_distro":"ubuntu","stid":[35],"ips":{"155":"192.158.234.110"}}}
```

Its getting splitted in two, so the JSON parser gives me an error.

The problem is that:

- Java is not receiving the correct number of byte length.
  How can I send the byte lenght from PHP and receive it in Java.

Comment: Because `cached_disk` is PHP serialized data not JSON.  We can't tell where/how this is happening.

Comment: Either fix the source, or whatever in PHP returns that data first needs to decode the JSON, unserialize the `cached_disk` and then JSON encode it all.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, but it's correctly encoded within the JSON, and this isn't an issue with attempting to decode that. Though it will likely be the very next question. :P

Comment: I would venture that the problem is in your Java code where `receive()` retrieves what is _currently available_, not necessarily the entire message. What I would suggest is better considering your protocol design, eg: transmitting the message length first, and then reading that number of bytes off the wire so you know you've gotten the whole thing. Or _something_ that has an awareness of where the message begins and ends, as opposed to just blindly reading bytes off the wire.

Comment: @Sammitch I looked over, thats the problem. How can I send the lenght and then receive it in Java?

Comment: Also, I don't remember enough Java to dissect all that code but `println` adds a newline, maybe use `print`.

Comment: Or build up a string and at the end `println` it.

Comment: The problem is the byte lenght.
So how can I send the lenght in PHP and receive it in Java?

Comment: `pack('n', $length)` will give you a 2-byte, big-endian representation and then _something something_ [ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530913/1064767)? I am not a Java dev.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added `Thread.sleep(100);` before calling `receive()` method.
This helped the program to get all available bytes so now I'm getting the string correctly.

Comment: Just be aware that this is a kludge, adds overhead, and longer messages and/or higher latencies will cause this behaviour to resurface.